# How can i Access a control into a class?

Tags: asp.net

I Have a Gridview in page.aspx. this gridview i want to pass as a parameter to the constructor of a class1.cs.Can anybody tel me, How can this be done?

Comment: Which GridView? Or is this not asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 1):

So you've got a page with a Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv1" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
</asp:GridView>

<div>
    This is where the count of rows of your GridView will be displayed:
    <p>
        <strong><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lCount" /></strong>
    </p>
</div>
```

And, in the codebehind you populate it like this:

```
this.gv1.DataSource = FullName.GetDemoCollection(); //Just returns a List<string>;
gv1.DataBind();
```

And you have another class `GridViewRowCounter` that does something with GridView, e.g. counts the rows:

```
public class GridViewRowCounter
{
    private System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView _gv;

    public GridViewRowCounter(){}

    public GridViewRowCounter(System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView _GV){
        this._gv = _GV;

    }

    public int GetRowCount(){
        return _gv.Rows.Count;
    }

}
```

So, to pass your GridView to the Gridviewcounter class you can do something like:

```
public partial class PassingControls : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Bind the GridView
        this.gv1.DataSource = FullName.GetDemoCollection();//
        gv1.DataBind();

        //Pass Gridview reference to the GridVeiwRowCounter constructor.
        GridViewRowCounter gvcounter = new GridViewRowCounter(this.gv1);
        //Get the external class to return the rowcount from your GridView.
        this.lCount.Text = gvcounter.GetRowCount().ToString();
    }
}
```

HTH.

I *hope* this is what you were asking ;-)

Comment: Thank for spending time to answer me but,Sorry! u misinterpret my question.:-) Actually I want to pass Gridview as a parameter to a class Something like this                             Class Myclass
{
public Myclass(Gridview gv)
{
// Some Code
}
}      The above code need to be there in in a class. The Gridview i want to pass from an .aspx page. i guess some namespace has to be added to the class to get gridview as a datatype in the constructor. How to do this?

Comment: I really am confused - if you look at the code for the `GridViewRowCounter` class above you'll see that it has 2 constructors - one is the default one that takes no parameters and the other is:

`public GridViewRowCounter(System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView _GV){
        this._gv = _GV;
}`

which you can see takes a GridView as a parameter. Isn't this what you mean?

Comment: i mean am not able to get the keyword gridview in the class.

Comment: Are you using the correct namespace? Do you have `using System.Web.UI.Webcontrols;` at the top of your code? If you can't 'see' this namespace in your class you might need to add a reference to it to your project via Visual Studio solution Explorer.